# API not working with Javascript window.location

Tags: javascript

I need to find a way for an api url to use the actual page that is open to convert the page to a pdf. The link that I have does not work - it just takes the user back to the web application log in page. Any ideas?

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href='http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/urltopdf?apikey=yourapikey&url=' + escape(window.location.href)">Save this page as PDF</a>
```

Also, if I wanted to encode the url how would I add that?

Thanks

Comment: why doesn't this work?

Comment: Is it really using the verb GET?

Comment: My application opens a pop up page of the report that needs to be converted to PDF. This link is in the pop up page but when I click it it is just changing the pop up page to the log in page and not downloading the pdf. Is it poosibly an url encode issue?

Answer (score 0):

The [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) function is deprecated, you should use [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Assuming that you have put in a valid API key, I don't really see anything wrong with what you posted.

If the problem remains I suggest you contact the html2pdf.co.uk support [here](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/contact/).

Good luck, hope this helps.

Edit:

In the [official documentation](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/save-as-pdf/) they suggest you use this link:

```
<a href="http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/display">Save this page as PDF</a>
```

Did you try that?

Comment: Hi Tim-We - managed to find an alternative solution - thanks for your help